# Read from XML into editable html textbox, Write back on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem. I've tried multiple sources but haven't found a solid answer. I created an HTML page that has some Javascript and some PHP. I  have an XML (or text file) that has user information tags (name, number, Car number, etc.). When I load the webpage, I'd like it to automatically create the fields based on the tags and the data in those tags, so if I need to edit the car number or the driver name I can change it and hit submit. On page reload, the new data is there in a textbox and still editable for the next round.

I've done other things with flat files, but I heard that XML is the right way to go. I'm open to all other suggestions though.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RACELANE>
    <CARNUMBER>1</CARNUMBER>
    <DRIVER>Erick Buque</DRIVER>
    <CARMAKE>Nissan</CARMAKE>
    <CARMODEL>350Z</CARMODEL>
    <YEAR>2011</YEAR>
    <CARNUMBER>2</CARNUMBER>
    <DRIVER>Sean Smith</DRIVER>
    <CARMAKE>Chevy</CARMAKE>
    <CARMODEL>Cobalt SS</CARMODEL>
    <YEAR>2010</YEAR>
    <CARNUMBER>3</CARNUMBER>
    <DRIVER>James Abbot</DRIVER>
    <CARMAKE>Honda</CARMAKE>
    <CARMODEL>Civic si</CARMODEL>
    <YEAR>2011</YEAR>
    <CARNUMBER>4</CARNUMBER>
    <DRIVER>Leigh Summers</DRIVER>
    <CARMAKE>Nissan</CARMAKE>
    <CARMODEL>Altima R</CARMODEL>
    <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
    <CARNUMBER>5</CARNUMBER>
    <DRIVER>Rick Littleton</DRIVER>
    <CARMAKE>Ford</CARMAKE>
    <CARMODEL>Mustang</CARMODEL>
    <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
</RACELANE>
```

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest you look at MySQL and storing the data in a database. Flat files can only go so far and I'm sure you'll run into problems in the future with them.

Comment: @JamesWalker I am experiencing the limitations of flat files now. I have MySQL installed on my device, it's an option if I can't get further with the flat file. At least with the database, I wont have two drivers with the same number.

Comment: I added a sample of the XML that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simpleXML to retrieve data from an xml file

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . ": <input type='text' name='" . $child->getName() . "' value='" . $child . "'><br>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
?>
```

and to save it back put this on the beginning of your php

```
<?php 
$newXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<data></data>");
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    if($key != 'submit')
    $newXML->addChild($key,$value);
}
$newXML->asXML('data.xml'); //write it back to file
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented it, It comes up the way it needs to, I can't seem to get it to submit the changes and update the xml file though.

Comment: can you give more specifics, did you check what $_POST variable is returning? did you check if the $newXML variable is correctly constructed? did you check if there is a permission problem writing to data.xml?

Comment: I basically put both statements in one file. I'm not sure if that was the correct way to go.

Comment: can you post the full code? or even better put it on somewhere we can test?

Comment: I'm not sure if i got the output of $_POST right. but I reconstructed the $newXML and I double checked the permission. So there was a problem with the permission, and I fixed that part. I put the code on my blog. Bear with me, Its' my first post. [link]http://joanthangirwarnath.blogspot.com/2014/02/version1.htm

Comment: so does the code create a XML file successfully now? if yes, is it in the format you need or needs formatting?

Comment: unfortunately no. its overwriting the file, but it comes out like this: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RACELANE>
 <CARNUMBER/>
 <DRIVER/>
 <CARMAKE/>
 <CARMODEL/>
 <YEAR/>
</RACELANE>`

Comment: change this: `$newXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<RACEWAY>
 <CARNUMBER></CARNUMBER>
 <DRIVER></DRIVER>
 <CARMODEL></CARMODEL>
 <CARMAKE></CARMAKE>
 <YEAR></YEAR>
</RACEWAY>");` to this `$newXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<RACEWAY></RACEWAY>");`

Comment: I wrapped the php load_file in a form tag. `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Comment: Its on the right track, but its only echoing /rewriting the last driver info. the rest is gone.

Comment: I'd also recommend using a database like MySQL. Manipulating this XML file will get more complicated in time and its better to change now then later.

Comment: I think I might have to actually go that way. If I make progress with this, I'll be sure to post.Thanks for your help @Volkan Ulukut

Comment: I hope you make progress with it. accepting answer / upvoting is a good way to thank me :)